# SMPP - Source address coming as "Unknown" when use an alphanumeric source address

Tags: node.js, smpp

For some reason when I use an alphanumeric source address, it is coming as "unknown".

Test cases

1. p - Works fine (Getting from a source address called "p")
2. pm - Getting from a source address called "unknown"
3. pmm - Works fine (Getting a from a source address called "pmm")

The issue occurs only when I use an alphanumeric source address with 2 characters

I am using the below smpp client

[Shorty](https://github.com/Roave/shorty)

Answer (score 0):

After an in-depth research and various tests, I found the issue is only happening in i-phones. I contacted the SMPP provider regarding this and they said, unfortunately they can't do anything on this since it's an iOS issue.

Finally, I added a validation to check the number of characters in the source address to solve this issue (Between 3 and 11).